# Google Charts: Drawing Multiple Bar Charts with dual axis in IE

Tags: jquery, charts, google-visualization, bar-chart

I'm creating multiple bar charts with dual axis on the same page. It works fine in chrome but **it doesn't work in IE**. In IE it shows an error

> "Object doesn't support property or method 'contains'"

HTML & JavaScript code as follows:

```js
      

startChart();
      function startChart() {
       
          var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
              ['Galaxy', 'Distance', 'Brightness'],
              ['Canis Major Dwarf', 8000, 23.3],
              ['Sagittarius Dwarf', 24000, 4.5],
              ['Ursa Major II Dwarf', 30000, 14.3],
              ['Lg. Magellanic Cloud', 50000, 0.9],
              ['Bootes I', 60000, 13.1]
          ]);

          var options = {
              width: 900,
              chart: {
                  title: 'Nearby galaxies',
                  subtitle: 'distance on the left, brightness on the right'
              },
              series: {
                  0: {
                      axis: 'distance'
                  }, // Bind series 0 to an axis named 'distance'.
                  1: {
                      axis: 'brightness'
                  } // Bind series 1 to an axis named 'brightness'.
              },
              axes: {
                  y: {
                      distance: {
                          label: 'parsecs'
                      }, // Left y-axis.
                      brightness: {
                          side: 'right',
                          label: 'apparent magnitude'
                      } // Right y-axis.
                  }
              }
          };

          var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('dual_y_div'));
          chart.draw(data, options);
  var chart1 = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('dual_y_div1'));
          chart1.draw(data, options);

      };
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={'modules':[{'name':'visualization','version':'1.1','packages':['bar']}]}"></script>
<div id="dual_y_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
<div id="dual_y_div1" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following is an example, with the changes needed, for multiple [Material Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart#creating-material-column-charts)

```js
google.charts.load('41', {packages: ['bar']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(startChart);

function startChart() {

  var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Galaxy', 'Distance', 'Brightness'],
    ['Canis Major Dwarf', 8000, 23.3],
    ['Sagittarius Dwarf', 24000, 4.5],
    ['Ursa Major II Dwarf', 30000, 14.3],
    ['Lg. Magellanic Cloud', 50000, 0.9],
    ['Bootes I', 60000, 13.1]
  ]);

  var options = {
    width: 900,
    chart: {
      title: 'Nearby galaxies',
      subtitle: 'distance on the left, brightness on the right'
    },
    series: {
      0: {
        axis: 'distance'
      }, // Bind series 0 to an axis named 'distance'.
      1: {
        axis: 'brightness'
      } // Bind series 1 to an axis named 'brightness'.
    },
    axes: {
      y: {
        distance: {
          label: 'parsecs'
        }, // Left y-axis.
        brightness: {
          side: 'right',
          label: 'apparent magnitude'
        } // Right y-axis.
      }
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('dual_y_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
  var chart1 = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('dual_y_div1'));
  chart1.draw(data, options);
};
```

```html
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="dual_y_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  <div id="dual_y_div1" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Awesome finding @WhiteHat. Now it worked. But  adding meta tag is not encouraged for production use because of the possible unexpected results of rendering page content. Thanks.

Comment: Removed IE distinction from answer, reported [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33417224/5090771) that it fixed other browsers as well...

Comment: Would you mind to document what is the actual fix? Perhaps in the form of a diff patch. That will help those who arrive here with the same problem and need the same fix applied to their code.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is still a bug of the google visualization api.
([link](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2039))

However, I changed the Bar chart into a columnChart and changed the options for the axis so that they work with the column chart and it did the trick.

However this https://jsfiddle.net/5b8au8t4/1/ is working.

```js
startChart();
      function startChart() {
       
          var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
              ['Galaxy', 'Distance', 'Brightness'],
              ['Canis Major Dwarf', 8000, 23.3],
              ['Sagittarius Dwarf', 24000, 4.5],
              ['Ursa Major II Dwarf', 30000, 14.3],
              ['Lg. Magellanic Cloud', 50000, 0.9],
              ['Bootes I', 60000, 13.1]
          ]);

          var options = {
              width: 900,       
              title: 'Nearby galaxies',
              vAxes: {
   0: {
    title: 'parsecs',
    
    },
   1: {
    title: 'apparent magnitude',
    
   },
          },
              series: {
   0:{
    targetAxisIndex:0,
    
    },
   1:{
    targetAxisIndex:1,
    
    },
            },
          };
          var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('dual_y_div'));
          chart.draw(data, options);
  var chart1 = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('dual_y_div1'));
          chart1.draw(data, options);

      }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={'modules':[{'name':'visualization','version':'1.1','packages':['corechart']}]}"></script>
<div id="dual_y_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
<div id="dual_y_div1" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

I'm hoping that this will help you.

Comment: Thank you so much. I changed this to ColumnChart as you mentioned and it's working.