# Google Chart doesn't display when drawing multiple charts dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, google-visualization, linechart

I receive some datas with ajax, and I would like to display it as google line charts. I don't know how many chart I have to display, so I have made it dynamic using a javascript `forEach` to call my function `drawchart();`

Here I receive the datas :

```
$j.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "../"+folder_destination+"slimrest/getValues",
        data: "",
        success: function(msg){
            msg.forEach(function(entry) {
                drawchart(entry['id'], entry['data']);
            });
        }
});
```

Here is my function which is supposed to add a div with a unique ID then draw the chart inside :

```
function drawchart(id_rec){

    $j("#charts_cartes").append("<div id=\"gchart_"+id_rec+"\"></div>");

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('number', 'max');
    data.addColumn('number', 'min');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Mesures');

    //Will be dynamic as soon as I'll be able to print more than one chart
    data.addRows([
      [1,  37.8, 80.8],
      [2,  30.9, 69.5]
    ]);

    var options = {
      width: 500,
      height: 200
    };

    var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('gchart_'+id_rec));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

I see my divs in the html code, but the second chart is never displayed.

[image: source code]

It seems that the `<svg></svg>` balise is empty for one of the charts :

```
<div id="charts_cartes">
    <div id="gchart_39">
        <div style="position: relative; width: 500px; height: 200px;">
            <div
                style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
                <svg width="500" height="200">
                    <defs><!-- [chart code well displayed but too long to write here] --></defs>
                </svg>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="gchart_40">
        <div style="position: relative; width: 500px; height: 200px;">
            <div
                style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
                <svg width="500" height="200">
                <defs></defs></svg>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is a problem/bug with displaying multiple _material_ charts. This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32907208/5090771) should help...

Comment: Thanks for the update. I didn't think it could be a google-visualisation issue ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem fixed adding a setTimeout to the draw function of the googlechart :

```
setTimeout(function(){ chart.draw(data, options); }, 1000);
```

There must be some conflicts if drawing to much charts almost simultaneously ...

Answer (score 1):

The solution above works, but setTimeout with just 1 millisecond works, so that if you're dynamically generating the charts with some display logic, it won't be loading for 1000 milliseconds.

So this also worked for me in an AngularJS app.

```js
setTimeout(function(){ chart.draw(data, options); }, 1);
```